# line breaks in Jade conditionals

Tags: pug

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to insert line breaks in a Jade template conditional.  For example, consider the following lengthy conditional:

```
if superlongstatementnumberone == true && superlongstatementnumbertwo == false && superlongstatementnumberthree == true
  div: span some content
```

would be much more manageable as:

```
if superlongstatementnumberone == true \
  && superlongstatementnumbertwo == false \
  && superlongstatementnumberthree == true
  div: span some content
```

it is possible to do this with non-conditional parts but the above does not work with code statements according to my experimentation.  It sort of inconceivable to me that a language could reach the penetration of Jade without any support for this.

I hope this post will prove me right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) with a leading `-` minus (word seperator) like described in the offical [Jade - Language Reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/)

Newer Jade/Pug versions supports code blocks of buffered and unbuffered code with a sinlg minus with the indentation of following lines, like this example:

```
- 
  if (superlongstatementnumberone == true 
    && superlongstatementnumbertwo == false 
    && superlongstatementnumberthree == true) {
      var someContent = 'some content'
  }
div: span= someContent
```

In older Jade/Pug versions you need to add the leading `-` minus to all lines, like in this example:

```
- if (superlongstatementnumberone == true 
-   && superlongstatementnumbertwo == false 
-   && superlongstatementnumberthree == true) {
-      var someContent = 'some content'
- }
div: span= someContent
```

Take a look on a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/zBJLgy).